# How to compare two adjacent rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL is there a way to compare two adjacent rows. In other words if C2 = BEM and C3 = Compliance or if C4 = Compliance and C5 = BEM, then return true. But consecutive rows are identical like in C6 = BEM and C7 = BEM, then return fail.

[image]

Comment: Nothing in your data is called `n`, so it is quite unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Seems you assume rows have an order that can be used in a query. They don't, so your goal is impossible without additional columns. Do they exist that define the order you need to evaluate row n with row (n+1)?

Comment: Could one of the answerers check their logic?  I don't know how the LEAD function works, and the 2 answers directly contradict each other in terms of which is PASS and which is FAIL.

Comment: _order by 1, 2_ is not helpful (nor a good practice since you are ordering by ordinal position). To use lag and lead, one needs to use the appropriate column names, so answer my question. Better yet, post DDL for the table (or tables) involved.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter: a SQL table represents an *unordered* set of rows; there is no inherent ordering. Assuming that you have a column that defines the ordering of the rows, say `id`, and that your values are stored in column `col`, you can use  `lead()` and a `case` expression as follows:

```
select col,
    case when col = lead(col, 1, col) over(order by id) 
        then 'Fail' else 'OK' 
    end as status
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort of column that you can use to determine the row order then you can use the **LEAD** window function to get the next value.

```
SELECT 
  [A],
  CASE 
    WHEN [A] = LEAD([A], 1, [A]) OVER (ORDER BY SomeSortIndex) THEN 'Fail' 
    ELSE 'Ok' 
  END [B]
FROM src
```

The additional parameters in the **LEAD** function specify the row offset and default value in case there is no additional row.  By using the current value as the default it will cause the condition to be true and display *Fail* like the last result in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [lead()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [lag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) functions.

They do work best (most reliable) with a sorting field... Your sample does not appear to contain such a field. I added a sorting field in my second solution.

The [coalesce()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function handles the first row that does not have a preceeding row.

**Solution 1** without sort field

```
create table data
(
  A nvarchar(10)
);

insert into data (A) values
('BEM'),
('Compliance'),
('BEM'),
('Compliance'),
('BEM'),
('Compliance'),
('Compliance'),
('Compliance');

select d.A,
       coalesce(lag(d.A) over(order by (select null)), '') as lag_A,
       case
         when d.A <> coalesce(lag(d.A) over(order by (select null)), '')
         then 'Ok'
         else 'Fail'
       end as B
from data d;
```

**Solution 2** with sort field

```
create table data2
(
  Sort int,
  A nvarchar(10)
);

insert into data2 (Sort, A) values
(1, 'BEM'),
(2, 'Compliance'),
(3, 'BEM'),
(4, 'Compliance'),
(5, 'BEM'),
(6, 'Compliance'),
(7, 'Compliance'),
(8, 'Compliance');

select d.A,
       case
         when d.A <> coalesce(lag(d.A) over(order by d.Sort), '')
         then 'Ok'
         else 'Fail'
       end as B
from data2 d
order by d.Sort;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee9520361f459b30d2dcba2cd60387b4) with results.

Comment: I modified your code to meet unforeseen needs. In instances where the lead and the lag are equal, I want it to return "FAIL". How do I do that? 
 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f337fbff2373f33d2c7d7721b496e59

Comment: Like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0893ff546bf0b088cc28f6a38b41fa85). Add the coalesce function where needed.

Comment: It is not working. Here is what I tried 

select d.sort, 
d.A,
       case
         when ( d.A = coalesce(lag(d.A) over(order by d.Sort), '')  and d.A = coalesce(lead(d.A) over (order by d.sort), '') )then 'FAIL'
  
         when d.A <> coalesce(lag(d.A) over(order by d.Sort), '')  then 'Ok'
         when d.A <> coalesce(lead(d.A) over (order by d.sort), '') then 'ok'
  
  
     
       end as B
from data2 d
order by d.Sort;


https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=38cfeca5ad34dae9d8e2f5be08454efa

Comment: The fiddle from my previous comment compares the previous and next row (the "lead" and "lag" as described in your first comment). Your version also compares those values with the current row. This indeed [produces different results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2188b5e5f72ab2d849b391f067a1bbba).

Comment: you suggestion did not work. I am trying to compare cells in blocks of two. If cell A1 = compliance and A2 = business or A1 = business and A2 compliance, then ok. Else if, A1 = compliance and A2 = compliance, then Fail.